# Need a little Array direction pointing (Dynamic Arrays in PHP)

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I am working on a project in PHP & MySQL, I have a Table with an expandable amount of fields. I have been looking for a way to work out an array system to handle this but am unsure. I am not looking for someone to code it for me but would like opinions on the best way to handle it.

Exp:

```
TABLE Stage one:
ID    OPTION1  OPTION2
1     dirt     drop
2     ground   lake
3     clay     pond
```

Now to explain what I am looking to do: I need to create a way to allow my arrays to see all the fields and make an array for each once so.

Exp:

```
$arrayone(dirt,ground,clay);
$arraytwo(drop,lake,pond);
```

But if I add a new field to my Database like so:

Exp:

```
TABLE Stage one:
ID    OPTION1  OPTION2   OPTION3
1     dirt     drop      sky
2     ground   lake      cloud
3     clay     pond      sun
```

I need it to see the new field and allow for another array to be created on proccess..

Exp:

```
$arrayone(dirt,ground,clay);
$arraytwo(drop,lake,pond);
$arraythree(sky,cloud,sun);
```

Like I said I have been looking but not sure what I need to be looking for if anyone know and if it can be done could you point me to some references I can read up on to create.

I have this EXP:

```
$stringfromdb = "1,2,3,4";
$stringfromdb = "5,6,7,8";
```

Now i want to my php to take these two strings and build Arrays like

```
$arrayone(1,5);
$arraytwo(2,6);
$arraythree(3,7);
$arrayfour(4,8);
```

But if i was to add more to the string later like

```
$stringfromdb = "1,2,3,4,9,10";
$stringfromdb = "5,6,7,8,11,12";
```

I would need it to creat new arrays based off the new added sections of the string..

```
$arrayone(1,5);
$arraytwo(2,6);
$arraythree(3,7);
$arrayfour(4,8);
$arrayfive(9,11);
$arraysix(10,12);
```

I do plan on using some form of explode(); to split the scripts at the separators. Not sure if this helps at all.. to get my issue across lol sorry...

Comment: An expandable amount of field? What's that? Doesn't sound good. SEE NORMALIZATION

Comment: right now i have just 6 fields, but i want to be able to add new fields with out reediting the code...

Comment: U should use a `cross reference table` for this. One table containing the options (`option_id, title`) , one table containing the values (`value_id, title`) and one table for combining them (`option_id, value_id`)

Answer (score 1):

Not really sure I understood your goal entirely, but I've worked on a project with similar structure, and it was done like so:

```
id  | field | value
----+-------+------
1   | opt1  | dirt
1   | opt2  | ground
1   | opt3  | clay
2   | opt1  | apple
2   | opt2  | banana
2   | opt3  | melon
```

All snugly fits into single table. The table has a composite primary key: `(id, field)`. It might also be a good idea to have an index on those two columns.

Since you have a fixed number of columns, adding a "field" is as easy as adding one entry for each ID.

You can also have a "structure" table describing how many and what fields are required for the items.

Obviously, the SQL queries will not be as simple as with a simple table you have now, but it is much more practical.

Comment: I'd use 3 tables over 1 table to reduce redundancy of data

Comment: Yeah, it would make sense to have a fields table with numeric IDs for the fields, I guess. It could make it more efficient, but also adds complexity.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a normal two dimensional array to me - $array = array(array('dirt', 'ground', 'clay'), array('drop', 'lake', 'pond')...), unless I didn't understand the question...